# Keyboard plugin error when adding splash screen plugin

Tags: cordova-plugins, ionic-framework, ngcordova

when I add the splashscreen plugin:

```
cordova plugin add org.apache.cordova.splashscreen
```

and then add ios as platform, then I get the next error:

```
Failed to install 'com.ionic.keyboard':CordovaError: could not find -Info.plist file, or config.xml file.
```

Does anybody knows why this error is showing up?

Comment: Can you try removing platform, and then installing plugin, then installing platform?

Comment: I already treed that. But it doesn't work. I removed the keyboard plugin now for the time being